# What are the changes I should make to the .htaccess file to enable clean URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

What actually are the steps to clean the URL of a site.

I have made the following changes in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What are the changes I need to do in a .htaccess file so that I could enable clean URLs?

Comment: Seems better suited for serevr fault. You need your Drupal to "see" index.php?q=/some/path if there is no physical file under given real path. The rest is purely server dependent and does not depend on the CMS you're using.

Comment: Mołot i want my site to like /some/path instead of    ?q=some/path.I had made changes in 000-default file but don't know what exactly need to be done in .htaccess file.

Comment: Drupal needs to "receive" $_GET['q'] variable, but creating it from user friendly address input is purely server thing.

Comment: On the assumption that this is talking specifically Drupal, then I don't necessarily think it should be closed.  However - the [documentation is pretty clear on the setup](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls). Perhaps a little RTFM is in order? ;-)

Comment: The question should be edited to make it a Drupal question. I would suggest to read the documentation pointed by @Chapabu and then ask a question if you don't understand something in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do any edits in the Drupal default `.htaccess` file to have *Drupal 7* enable clean URLs.  Instead, navigate to *Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata* (its the link named "Clean URLs" on the Admin's Configuration page, and press the button "Run the clean URL test".

If the test is successful, Drupal will make use of its default `.htaccess` to do the rewrites.  If the test fails, then you need to review your configuration.

Some suggestions:

Make sure that the Drupal default `.htaccess` is present in your webroot (`/var/www`).

Make sure that you've actually enabled `mod_rewrite` for Apache, e.g.:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You must also restart Apache after changing defaults, e.g.:

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

(The example shell commands above are for Ubuntu.  If you run a different dialect of GNU/Linux, you may need to use slightly different shell commands.)

Comment: The test is failing so how should i review the Apache configuration ie what should i do to make the test successful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the default `.htaccess` file present in you Drupal root directory. You can try this

1. Download the fresh copy of Drupal.
2. Copy the `.htaccess` file, from the newly downloaded Drupal tarball to your sites root directory.
3. Run the test again.